# Apex to run report and cast the data to an SObject?

Tags: apex, api, reporting

I have a list of report Ids that I need to run, take action on the data such as creating a record, and then send that report data to an email address.

These reports all have different criteria, filters etc., so we are trying to not have to go down the route of hardcoding criteria in apex and using soql to handle this like a standard practice would be.

For this approach, I am using the apex analytics report data:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_report_data.htm

For now, I am trying to get this to work with a single report.

```
// ID of the report we are running
String reportId = '00O6T000006SnpABC';

// Run Report
Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId,true);
```

Next, I store the headers in a list so I can access them later.

```
// Hold the headers for the report
List<String> header = new List<String>();

// Access our headers
for (String colName : results.getReportMetadata().getDetailColumns()) {
    String label = results.getReportExtendedMetadata().getDetailColumnInfo().get(colName).getLabel();
    header.add(label);
}
```

In order to get the data, I am using `Reports.ReportFactWithDetails`. I loop through the rows and the cells so I can access the data row by row.

```
// Iterate over the factMap rows
Reports.ReportFactWithDetails factWithDetails = (Reports.ReportFactWithDetails) results.getFactMap().get('T!T');

// For each row 
for (Reports.ReportDetailRow row : factWithDetails.getRows()) {
    
    // For each cell
    Integer cellIndex = 0;
    for (Reports.ReportDataCell cell : row.getDataCells()) {
        Object value = cell.getLabel();
        String column = header.get(cellIndex);
        cellIndex++;
        
        // Debug
        System.debug('Column: ' + column + ' > Value: ' + value);
    }
    
}
```

What I would like to do is store this data in a better format so I can use it a bit easier. My thought was to create a list of the data with the key/value being the header name (aka the field) and the value is the value of the cell.

**Example:**

```
[{
    "Header 1": Row 1 Cell 1, 
    "Header 2": Row 1 Cell 2, 
    "Header 3": Row 1 Cell 3,
},
{
    "Header 1": Row 2 Cell 1, 
    "Header 2": Row 2 Cell 2, 
    "Header 3": Row 2 Cell 3,
},
{
    "Header 1": Row 3 Cell 1, 
    "Header 2": Row 3 Cell 2, 
    "Header 3": Row 3 Cell 3,
}]
```

**Question:**

I am trying to figure out the best way to store this in my desired format. Since all of the headers could be different for each of the reports, my approach on using a wrapper doesn't seem to work unless the structure can be dynamically created.

Any suggestions on how to best hold this data as if it were an SObject so it's a bit easier to manage when I need to start use it in the code later on?

If there is a better approach than doing the for loops, that would be ideal but it was all I could think of at the time.

Comment: Hi @SBB were you able to achieve it? How did you manage the groupings? as that data is very complicated.. I am doing something similar I want to send html table in Email but as you pointed out the wrapper would not be useful as structure is complex and dynamic let me know if you achieved it.